# Add fields to shipping (and customer) address in checkout process

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

I know that I can add "Address lines" in `Stores > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options > Number of Lines in a Street Address` but the address is stored as a single String in `quote_address` table.

I need to have four separate fields for customer address:

- Street
- Number
- Complement
- District

And

- Area code (before telephone field)

I'd like to show them in that order...

I've already created the `number, complement, district, area_code` columns in `quote_address` and `customer_address_entity`tables. Now I need to show it in frontend and save the custom data to these columns.

Any hints on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Any solutions, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Please review belwo link;

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Thanks